# Why will execl(...) on the find program from find-utils not output anything?

Tags: c++, linux, find, exec

I wrote a simple test program to try to call execl(...) with the path of the find command as a test. There is no output on stdout, no matter the parameters sent to the find program. Why is this happening? Here's the program:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cerrno>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if(execl("/usr/bin/find", "/usr/bin/find", "/", "-maxdepth", "1", "-name", "bin", (char*)NULL) == -1)
    {
        perror("In QueryRequest::Client_Execute(): ");
        _exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the compilation and run test of the program above; note that there is no output from it. Executing find from the console with the above parameters yields non-empty output. What is the problem here and how can I get past it?

```
[main@main-pc src]$ g++ test.cpp -o test
[main@main-pc src]$ ./test
[main@main-pc src]$
```

The specific meta-info about the targeted system:

```
Linux 4.9.66-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Nov 30 14:08:24 UTC 2017
```

Using the -print argument to find does not change the outcome. The behaviour is as expected on other systems, including a 4.9.66-1-MANJARO and another ARCH-based proprietary distro using a 4.11 kernel. I've compiled it with g++ 7.2 and other 4.x versions.

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: Works for me too.

Comment: Edit your Q to show the output of `uname -srv` . Good luck.

Comment: Once upon a very long time ago, you needed to add `-print`.  I’m surprised if that makes it ‘work’, but it’s worth a try.

Comment: And FWIW, after fixing the `#include`s, it works for me too...

Comment: regarding: `int main(int argc, char** argv)`  neither of these parameter are being used.  This results in the compiler outputting two warning messages.  A good way to fix those warnings is to use the signature for main() of `int main( void )`

Comment: @user362924: I disagree. In practice, `argc` & `argc` should *always* be used. See [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/307472/40065)

Comment: Did you really run `./test`? If you typed `test` then you are using the builtin command [test(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch,  then if including the two parameters to `main()`, then the first two statements in the body of `main()` should be: `(void)argc;` and `(void)argv;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read carefully the documentation of [execl(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execl.3.html) and of the [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) system call (which gets called by `execl`).

Notice that `execl` and `execve` returns only on failure. When they are successful, they do not return (since the calling process is changing entirely its [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) to run the new [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable)).

To debug your issue, you could temporarily replace `/usr/bin/find` by `/bin/echo`, and/or perhaps also use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html), e.g. `strace ./test`.

BTW, using `test` as your program name is *poor taste*, since conflicting with the standard [test(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html) (e.g. the [bash `test` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-test)) .... So I strongly recommend using another name, e.g. `mytest` ....

Of course, read also carefully the documentation of [find(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html).

BTW, on my Debian system your program (renamed as `curious`) works and outputs `/bin`

Notice that you could avoid running a `find` process from your C program by using [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html).

Also, remember that C and C++ are different languages (and your code looks like C, but then you should `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <errno.h>`). Don't forget to compile with all warnings and debug info, so [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `-Wall -Wextra -g` for [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Learn to [use the debugger `gdb`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/).

Answer (score 0):

the posted code does not compile, with a C compiler.

Suggest using the following code:

```
#include <unistd.h>   // execl(), _exit()
#include <stdio.h>    // perror()

int main( void )
{
    execl("/usr/bin/find", "/usr/bin/find", "/", "-maxdepth", "1", "-name", "bin", NULL);
    perror("In QueryRequest::Client_Execute(): ");
    _exit(1);
}
```